# Center ggplot2 output image around x-axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot below shows some data I collected. It was plotted and saved using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(gate, (aes(V, I))) +
  geom_line()

ggsave("filename.png", width = 15, height = 7, units = "cm")
```

Is there a way to center the output image of the plot around the x-axis label? With that I mean that in my plot the x-label should be the center of the output picture, not the center of the plot region. (e.g. by adding whitespace to the right site of the plot)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding a theme layer and play a little bit with the dimensions (here i put 1 cm)?

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_line() + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,1,0,0), "cm"))
```

Comment: That would be possible. I just thought maybe there is a easy automated fix I didn't know about.